# Complex alias command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

I am trying to create a complex alias.

I have a lot of servers I have to ssh to and writing the entire command is quite annoying some times.
I created aliases for every machine:

```
alias machine1="ssh machine1 -l root"
alias machine2="ssh machine2 -l root",
```

but I wonder if I can create a dynamic alias.
`alias maxhinex="ssh machinex -l root"` so when I write machine1 in terminal goes to machine1 and when I write machine2 goes to machine2.

I'm asking this because I have like 50 servers so that means a lot of aliases. And if I have new servers that means new aliases. All of them are added to /etc/hosts.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function like that:

```
sshx () {
        ssh "machine$1" -l root
}
```

Then you should execute `sshx 1`